# insert the rows by calculating next few months estimated data in python data frame

Tags: python

I have about 12 months data and I would like to insert next 12 months data by calculating with python.

The data I've got is as below:

```
Month     No.1    No.2   No.3    No.4
Dec-20    530     7287   803     6024
Jan-21    824     7447   1111    6384
Feb-21    1104    7665   1559    6669
Mar-21    1379    8270   2031    6932
Apr-21    1654    8799   2534    7013
May-21    1901    9295   3061    7013
Jun-21    2276    9776   3596    7077
Jul-21    2914    13324  3808    7061
Aug-21    3329    10266  4054    7125
Sep-21    3829    10497  4255    7322
Oct-21    4304    10614  4353    7467
```

I want to add 380 to No.1 column and 160 to No.2, No.3 column and 360 to No.4 column and make estimated value for next 12 months. How can I possibly get desire output?
And expected data is as bleow:

```
    Month     No.1    No.2   No.3    No.4
    Dec-20    530     7287   803     6024
    Jan-21    824     7447   1111    6384
    Feb-21    1104    7665   1559    6669
    Mar-21    1379    8270   2031    6932
    Apr-21    1654    8799   2534    7013
    May-21    1901    9295   3061    7013
    Jun-21    2276    9776   3596    7077
    Jul-21    2914    13324  3808    7061
    Aug-21    3329    10266  4054    7125
    Sep-21    3829    10497  4255    7322
    Oct-21    4304    10614  4353    7467
    Nov-21    4684    10781  4520    7827
    Dec-21    5064    10948  4687    8187
    Jan-22    5444    11115  4854    8547
                   ....and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an insert statement(sql) in a block of loop code, with a counter(this is to restrict the number of times the statement in the loop block is run) .

The values in the columns(number 1-4), are they random values or you have specific numbers?

Comment: The numbers in columns up to Oct-21 have specific values. can i possibly make rows of estimated value through python?

Comment: Yes you can use random() function to generate random values